# Hyperledger fabric chaincodes are running older version even after deleteting the container

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

im working on fabric 1.2, developed chain codes in golang and deployed in local(4 peers in local i.e in same system)

when i do some changes in chaincode and upgrade to next version, it is still working on older version.

I tried docker rm -f chaincodeID,  then deleting chaincode using rm  /var/hyperledger/production/chaincode/chaincodeName

But still it doesn't reflect new changes.
How to solve this?

Comment: Please elaborate on how you upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

As I know,the upgrade process includes install the chaincode with a higher version on every peer and upgrade the chaincode with the same endorement policy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your upgrade process has some wrong...I think you'd better show us how you upgraded the chaincode.

Generally, you should first install the new version of the chaincode on every peer, then upgrade it with the same endorsement policy.

Comment: While this is not an answer, Please use comment section to ask additional or supplementary question. Thanks.